# Unity InterceptionBehavior don't get called

Tags: c#, unity-container

Im using unity and i like to use an InterceptionBehavior for logging. When i add the InterceptionBehavior to the type regestration nothing happens and the InterceptionBehavior isn't called.

Here is the Behavior class:

```
public class Logger : IInterceptionBehavior
{
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Methode {0} wurde aufgerufen",input.MethodBase.Name);
        return getNext.Invoke().Invoke(input, getNext);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
    {
        return Type.EmptyTypes;
    }

    public bool WillExecute => true;
}
```

And the type registration:

```
container.RegisterType<IParser, Parser>(
    new Interceptor(new InterfaceInterceptor()), 
    new InterceptionBehavior(new Logger()));

container.RegisterType<IBerechne, Berechne>(
    new Interceptor(new InterfaceInterceptor()),
    new InterceptionBehavior(new Logger()));
```

Comment: You may want to review your questions and accept the answers that helped, this may get more people interested in answering you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Interception for your Unity container. It is not enabled by default

```
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
```

See also [Interception using Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add new extension and ensure, your interface is `public`:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
container.RegisterType<IParser, Parser>(
            new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), 
            new InterceptionBehavior<Logger>());
```